# Sorting in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Could any one let me know how to implement sorting on GridView?

Comment: @Darin - nothing in the first page of search results points to stackoverflow, something that I feel needs fixing.... =) If everyone "tried google" hard enough there'd be no need for so.

Comment: Nothing on the first page? The first page contains nothing but samples of sorting. Try implementing some of the examples and if you encounter some difficulties or have a specific question don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @Darin - I didn't say there was nothing on the first page. I said *nothing in the first page of search results points to stackoverflow*. That's a failing that this question is the perfect opportunity to correct.

Comment: @Darin let him ask what he want! and if you can't help, there are others who can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had a look at some code I wrote a while ago that allows sorting on an `<asp:GridView>` and it would appear all I did was added `AllowSorting="True"` to the GridView tag and then `SortExpresssion="expression"` to the Column, for example:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="StatusId">
    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#1A3491" Width="130px"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle Height="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# (int)Eval("StatusId") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I did what you said but this is the error I get: "The GridView 'gvOutlookMeldingen' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled."